# Netty: Using a channel defined in the anonymous inner class within another method

Tags: java, connection, netty, channel, anonymous-inner-class

I have implemented a server-client connection in Netty, I can send and receive data between the two connections.

```
    public void start() 
    {
        // Start the interface
        bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try 
        {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                     @Override
                     public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                         log.debug("Socket established");
                         ch.pipeline().addLast(new SimulatorInboundHandler());
                         establishedChannel = ch;

                         interfaceEventsListeners.announce().interfaceConnected();

                         ByteBuf buff = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("Hello\n\r".getBytes());
                         ch.writeAndFlush(buff);

                     }

                 })
                 .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                 .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            ChannelFuture bindFuture = b.bind(simulatorConfiguration.getSimulationPort());

            bindFuture.await();

            sendData();

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            log.error("Interrupted", e);
        }
    }
```

The child handler creates an anonymous class to build the channel `ch`

I then save that channel to a global variable `establishedChannel`

In order to input live data into the connection I have created a method `sendData()`

```
public void sendData()
{
    Channel ch = establishedChannel;
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new SimulatorInboundHandler());
    ByteBuf buff = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("Hi\n\r".getBytes());

    if(ch != null)
    {
        ch.writeAndFlush(buff);
    }
    else
    {
        log.debug("No channel object attached");
    }

}
```

`ch` is continually identified as being null. How can I get by this issue?

Comment: Can you check if "ch" at initChannel is not null by using log.debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that initChannel(...) is called for each new Channel that was accepted and so calling sendData() after the bind future completes makes no sense.